# How to process and join string in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a list of strings - which are the properties names that I am interested in:
I want to join the values of these strings, but not using the properties name, but the properties values for them.
I saw that the starting point is `#strings.listJoin` - but how can I say to match the elements in the list against their value in the properties files?

The list would be: `[name, address]` and in the properties file I have:

```
name=stg
address=another something
```

I would like to obtain the string: `stg, another something`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it by utilizing `#messages.listMsg` and `#strings.listJoin`

Having the model returned from your @Controller:

```
model.addAttribute("messageKeyList", Lists.newArrayList("name", "address"));
```

You can join list of translated messages like this:

```
<div th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#messages.listMsg(messageKeyList), ',')}"></div>
```

Which should produce what you expect, e.g.:

```
Some name,Some address
```

Where name and address are keys in your messages file.

Comment: Does somebody know why my result list items are starting with '??' and ending with '_en_US??'
?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using localization, the *#messages.listMsg* part will try to translate each string in the list, resulting in what [@Oleksii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7459856/oleksii-morenets) mentioned in his comment above. If you want just to print the strings as-is, use this:

```
<div th:text="${#strings.listJoin(messageKeyList, ',')}"></div>
```