# How to convert List<String> to String with comma(,) separated

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a list of String like given below and I want to convert it into String with a comma(,) separated using thymeleaf.

```
List<String> scopeList = Arrays.asList("settings","locations","accounts","notifications");
```

I want to get output simply like this:

```
 settings,locations,accounts,notifications
```

Comment: using StringJoiner class

Comment: Is your question tag is correct ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959987/how-to-process-and-join-string-in-thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Java");
        list.add("Spring");
        list.add("Javascript");

        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
        list.forEach(sj::add);
        System.out.println(sj);
```

Output : Java,Spring,Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Checked with [CompileJava](https://www.compilejava.net/)

```
//*******************************************************************
// Welcome to CompileJava!
// If you experience any issues, please contact us ('More Info')  -->
//*******************************************************************

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<String> scopeList = Arrays.asList("settings","locations","accounts","notifications");
    System.out.print(scopeList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
  }
}
```

Output:

> settings,locations,accounts,notifications

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
List<string> scopeList= new List<string>() { 
"settings","locations","accounts","notifications" };  
var result = String.Join(",", scopeList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
String result = StringUtils.join(scopeList, ",");
```

Also, with Java 8, you can use *String.join*:

```
String result = String.join(",", scopeList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String scopeString = String.join(",", scopeList);
```